# Kali Linux 403 Forbidden [IP: 143.95.32.90 80] while running apt update

Tags: apt, kali-linux, repository

I know this question has been asked a lot of times but I'm completely stucked.

I have tried everything that i could possible think of about it. I am not able to update kali linux.

I have tried a lot of methods those are available on internet but no luck.

Also tried: https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories

Updated `sources.list` file too many times according to the solution but still error is not solved.

```
Version Details :PRETTY_NAME="Kali GNU/Linux Rolling"
NAME="Kali GNU/Linux"
ID=kali
VERSION="2019.2"
VERSION_ID="2019.2"
```

When I run the update command:

```
apt update
```

or

```
sudo apt-get update
```

**Terminal Error**

```
Err:6 http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb InRelease                                            
  403  Forbidden [IP: 143.95.32.90 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/xenial-getdeb/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 143.95.32.90 80]

E: The repository 'http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb InRelease' is not signed.

N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

**Soruces.list code**

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
```

Comment: `getdeb.net/ubuntu` doesn't look like a valid and secure Ubuntu repository. And why would you try to update Kali with Ubuntu? What's the error message if you use `deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib` in your `sources.list` and run `sudo apt-get update`? Please add the details to [your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/532542/edit). Thanks.

Comment: Generate same error after adding this code..

Comment: I don't know why it is update with ubuntu? can you tell me process how to remove 
Err:2 http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb InRelease                     
  403  Forbidden [IP: 143.95.32.90 80]

Comment: Thank you very much @telcoM . Successfully updated.

Comment: So that's all it was? I re-wrote my comment into a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

Does the directory 
`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` exist?

If it exists and there are files in it, they will be used as extensions to the main `sources.list` file. Either comment out any lines referring to archive.getdeb.net or move those files somewhere else, out of that directory altogether. Then try apt update again.

There's a rather common convention these days that if you see a configuration file named `<name>` and a directory `<name>.d` next to it, the directory will accept drop-in configuration file snippets that will be automatically included in the main configuration (either by an explicit include command, or implicitly). This allows easier automation, as dropping in a file with the required configuration snippet is easier and more reliable to do programmatically than modifying an existing text file.

In case of `sources.list[.d]`, it allows third-party packages to easily plug an additional `apt` repository in to facilitate their updates. You should be careful when adding packages from un-official repositories, since this capability can also easily used for evil purposes: if you accidentally install an evil Trojan-horse package that adds a configuration for an evil repository, the next time you update your system, you might be getting malicious "updates" to your system, simply because the packages in the evil repository can claim to be of just slightly newer version than the official ones.

In general, adding any third-party package repositories to Kali Linux, no matter how, is known to usually be a bad idea. The warning from Kali's documentation will also apply to the `sources.list.d` directory, although it doesn't explicitly say so:

> Any additional repositories added to the Kali sources.list file will most likely BREAK YOUR KALI LINUX INSTALL.

In particular, the getdeb.net site makes me suspicious: its current website attempts to be quite stylish and fancy, but has very little actual substance. Even some subscription offer pop-ups seem to be unfinished. To me, it looks like a fake site designed to trap the unwary.

[...And yes, even Wikipedia page for getdeb.net mentions that the current getdeb.net (since January 2019 at least) is a spam site, not to be trusted.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GetDeb)